# How to avoid a double serch and replace

Tags: python, search

I have the following code:
I need to rem out a line by placing a # at the begining.  It works great.
Problem is if the line is already remarked out by a #, and the query is run again. it places a second # in the line.  In the actual file "getweather.sh"  I end up with a line that looks like.   How can I search for the EXACT text?

```
####home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py
```

```
# Read in the file
with open('/home/pi/allsky/getweather.sh', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py', '#/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py')
# Write the file out again
with open('/home/pi/allsky/getweather.sh', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: I have another file that removes the # Rem from the line of text.

Comment: So run that other file first?

Comment: Problem is 2 files can turn it off, a third can remove it

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: I end up with multiple ####before the file.

Comment: When you run the file that **removes** it you get multiple? Huh?

Comment: If you're sure the line to be modified cannot be the first line in the file - then just add a newline character to the start of both the search and replacement strings.  That way, the modified line won't match again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reading in the entire file as a single string is the wrong approach; you can get the behavior you want more easily by calling `readlines()` to read in the file as an array of strings (one string per line of text) and handling it on a line-by-line basis instead, like this:

```
filePath = '/home/pi/allsky/getweather.sh'

# Read all lines of the file into an array of strings
with open(filePath, 'r') as inFile :
   inputLines = inFile.readlines()

# Write the array of strings back to the file, with # modification
with open(filePath, 'w') as outFile:
   for line in inputLines:
      line = line.strip()  # remove carriage-return/newline from the end
      if (line == '/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py'):
         outFile.write('#')
      outFile.write(line)
      outFile.write('\n')
```

Comment: the problem I have is IF the file was already rewritten with a # in the begining of the line, filedata = filedata.replace('/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py', '#/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py')  the next time around it sees #/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py and replaces it with ##/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py  when it should jusy ignore it.   if the button is pressed again, it appends the file with another  #  ###/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py  There is a thirs button that looks for the ata = filedata.replace('#/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py', '/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py')   or remove the remark.

Comment: @BobW So as expected you already have the code replace('#/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py', '/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py') ... Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: There are 2 buttons that when pressed I want the file line commented out.  If the same button is pressed again.  It adds another # to the file line when it should ignore it.   The third button removes the # from the line so the file can run when needed.

Comment: But why don't you want to run the removing code before the adding code? How does that not achieve the goal?

Comment: @BobW if there is already a `#` at the start of the line, then the `if (line == '/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py')` test won't succeed, and therefore no second `#` will be prepended.

Comment: This worked out very well.

Answer (score 0):

U can use re module to process string,avoid multi # wrtie to the file.

```
import re

filedata = re.sub("#.*?/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py", "#/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py", filedata)
```

Comment: I tied your suggestion.  I got an error.  Possibly I have it in the wrong place.   ~~~ File "/home/pi/dew-heater/heater_OFF.py", line 78, in
filedata = re.sub("#.*?/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py", "#/home/pi/allsky/get-temp.py", filedata)
NameError: name 're' is not defined~~~     DO I need this in with the rest of my program or in replacement of it?     Sorry I am new to coding.

Comment: Python module [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re) is a regular module and it needs to be imported using import statement.Update code